# curl command to submit google docs

Tags: ubuntu, curl, server, ubuntu-16.04, devops

I am facing a problem using the curl command, below is the command I need to submit:

```
curl "https://docs.google.com/a/floretmedia.com/forms/d/15TYyiIhPy4sj-PefWKqZgfYMhK6u56FX1m8rY2lodos/formResponse -d ifq -d entry.12885608=ubuntu -d submit=Submit​"
```

but when I type this I get the following error:

```
No command '​curl' found, did you mean:
Command 'curl' from package 'curl' (main)
curl: command not found
```

I already installed curl using

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

os : ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Have you already tried to install from source? 
https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html

Comment: how can i do this ? can you explain... for doing this ..

Comment: Don't install from source. Did you get any errors with the `apt-get install curl`? Does `which curl` output anything useful?

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
sudo apt-get install curl libc6 libcurl3 zlib1g -y
```